# After project conversion to Swift 3: "Type [Any] has no subscript members"

Tags: swift

I have recently migrated my project to Swift 3.0 and now getting the error "Type [Any] has no subscript members". My viewController and model.swift classes are attached. You can see below.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

it is in table viewController......

```
    // Configure the cell...
    let rowArray:AnyObject  = (model.allEmployees() [indexPath.row])

    print("ID = \(rowArray[0])")

    let fName = rowArray[1] as! String
    let lName = rowArray[2] as! String
    let fullName = "\(fName)\(lName)"
    let phone = rowArray[3] as! String

    cell.textLabel?.text = fullName
    cell.textLabel?.text = phone

    return cell
}
```

Here is my model.swift class:

```
-(NSArray *) allEmployees
{

    [self openDB];
    NSMutableArray *employeeData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

    //prepare the select query:
    NSString *selectSQL = @"SELECT names.ID, firstName, lastName, phone FROM Name INNER JOIN Phones WHERE Names.ID = phones.NamesID";
    const char *query = [selectSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *query_stmt = NULL;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &query_stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"error preparing %@", selectSQL);
        return nil;
    }
    while (sqlite3_step(query_stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        // for each row, bind the values to c types, then
        //convert to objects

    long long ID = sqlite3_column_int(query_stmt, 0);
    char *fName = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(query_stmt, 1);
    char *lName = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(query_stmt, 2);
    char *pNumber = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(query_stmt, 3);
    NSNumber *rowID = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:ID];
    NSString *firstName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:fName];
    NSString *lastName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:lName];
    NSString *phoneNumber = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:pNumber];

    //marshal the data:
    NSArray *entry = @[rowID,firstName,lastName,phoneNumber];
    [employeeData addObject:entry];
}
[self closeDB];
return employeeData;
```

Comment: What is the return type of model.allEmployees() ?

Comment: Regardless of the return type of .allEmployees, he's storing it as an AnyObject, which really doesn't have a subscript member. Perhaps he meant to store as an [AnyObject] or an NSArray?

Comment: Kindly Post output of " print(rowArray) rather than rowArray[0] "  and your model here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this :

```
if let employees = model.allEmployees() as? [[Any]] {
    let rowArray = employees[indexPath.row]
    let fName = rowArray[1] as! String
    let lName = rowArray[2] as! String
    let fullName = "\(fName)\(lName)"
    let phone = rowArray[3] as! String

    cell.textLabel?.text = fullName
    cell.textLabel?.text = phone
}
```

Comment: Better `let fName = rowArray[1] as? String ?? "Dummy"`